# Selenium webdriver-simulate user event of selecting words in online word search game

Tags: class, selenium, webdriver, action, mousemove

I want to simulate a real life scenario of selecting words in wordsearch online games. example word needs to be find is "School",,then I will click on the letter S and move towards rightside where letters C H O O L is present,On selecting/finding the word server will say successs.

consider I have identified the word,now want to clickon letter S and move towards right to select C H O O L.

how to do it ?

HTML:

```
<tbody> 
    <tr> 
        <td class="rf-tgrid">G</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">S</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">T</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">J</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">Z</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">N</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">P</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">H</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">M</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">C</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td class="rf-tgrid">S</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">N</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">N</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">A</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">L</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">V</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">F</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">X</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">H</td>
        <td class="rf-tgrid">K</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you please post some of the HTML of the website you want to interact with.

Comment: Attaching two rows each row has ten columns.. sample example

Comment: Jamie Rees,I know we can simulate the scenario with the help of Action Class in Webdriver,, But want to know how to do it :) :)

Comment: Ok, What language are you using? I wanted the HTML to provide a better answer

Comment: its internal application ,hence I shouldnt share it ..java

Comment: Am i clear with my requirement ???

Comment: Yes, you are now. I don't know much Java so I am doing it in C# and trying to convert it to Java for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, Apologies if there is any syntax errors, don't have a Java IDE

```
List<WebElement> allLetters= dropDown.findElements(By.className("rf-tgrid"));

for ( WebElement we: allLetters) { 
    if ( we.getText().contains( "Your school letters in some sort of List<> or Array[]"))
    {
       Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
       action.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
    }
```

Something like that should work.